# SharePoint 2010 Foundation site Read permission list item contribute permission not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I've upgraded a SharePoint WSS 3.0 farm to SharePoint 2010 Foundation.

Now I got a strange problem in a web part that modifies and creates Content Library files.

The user is only allowed to modify a file if he also got Contribute/Full access on site level (might be enough to have these permission on List/Library but I haven't tried). The user already got contribute permissions on the parent folder and on the file (inherits).

Another problem on the same site but on a different Library. All users on the site can read all files in this Library but when i try to copy a file from one list to another using the following code i get access denied when OpenBinaryStream is executed.

```
SPFile newFile = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["ToLibrary"].RootFolder.Files.Add(folder + "/default.aspx", oldFile.OpenBinaryStream());
```

Both the problems only occurs on the upgraded farm and works fine on the WSS 3.0 farm.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue which turned out to be a setting for lists/libraries.  In the Advanced Settings for a list/library, there is a section labeled "Item-Level Permissions" - this setting can be used to deny access for anyone without Full Control rights to the item.  Unless there is a specific need, Read Access should be set to Read all items and Create and Edit access should be set to Create and edit all items.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by going to Site Settings > Edit Permission Level > and giving the 'Contribute' permission level the ability to 'Open Items  -  View the source of documents with server-side file handlers'